# Возможно ли соотнести данные в разных узлах при помощи XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, lotus-notes

XSL не работает. Цикл в цикле неправильно сделан. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Здесь мой XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd'>
<database xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.8'
 replicaid='4525808B002B756C' path='sed\gecho\gecho_intgr.nsf' title='Госэкспертиза. Интеграция'
 fromtemplate='osn_tmpl_int' increasemaxfields='true'>

<database>
    <document form='Request'>
        <item name='noteid'><text>4CA5A</text></item>
    </document>

    <document form='Request'>
        <item name='noteid'><text>23953A</text></item>
    </document>

    <document form='Report'>
        <item name='obj_exp'>
            <textlist>
                <text>4CA5A:Нагорная А.Н.</text>
                <text>5CA9A:Иванов С.С.</text>
                <text>23953A:Носков И.Н.</text>
            </textlist>
        </item>
    </document>
</database>
```

Здесь мой XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="dxl:database/dxl:document[@form='Request']/dxl:item[@name='noteid']">
    <xsl:for-each select="dxl:database/dxl:document/dxl:item[@name='obj_exp']/dxl:textlist/dxl:text">
        <xsl:if test="dxl:database/dxl:document[@form='Request']/dxl:item[@name='noteid']='dxl:database/dxl:document/dxl:item[@name='obj_exp']/dxl:textlist/dxl:text'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text,':')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: В показанном xml нет пространств имен. Между тем в xslt есть префикс `dxl`. Чему он равен? Приведите больше информации.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил пространство имен в xml (xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl')

dxl - это префикс, который указывает, что преобразование идет не с чистым xml, а с dxl.  DXL - это Domino XML в системе IBM Notes

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="dxl:database/dxl:document[@form='Request']/dxl:item[@name='noteid']">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="./dxl:text"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="/dxl:database/dxl:document/dxl:item[@name='obj_exp']/dxl:textlist/dxl:text">

        <xsl:if test="$id=substring-before(.,':')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Символ `.` (точка) означает текущий узел. В первом цикле запоминаем его значение в переменную.

Внутри второго цикла точка будет указывать уже на его узлы.

Также второй цикл начинаем с корня - вначале xpath добавляем `/`. Иначе отсчет будет вестись с текущего узла первого цикла.

Внутри `if` сравниваем значение сохраненной переменной со значением текущего узла вложенного цикла.

Надеюсь, всё понятно.

---

Более правильным подходом для такого случая является использование `key`. По сути, это словарь (ассоциативный массив, хэш-таблица, dictionary).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">

<xsl:key name="list" match="dxl:database/dxl:document/dxl:item[@name='obj_exp']/dxl:textlist/dxl:text" use="substring-before(.,':')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="dxl:database/dxl:document[@form='Request']/dxl:item[@name='noteid']">

        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(key('list', .), ':')"/>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Привёл весь stylesheet полностью, чтобы было понятно, где задаётся `key` - вне любых шаблонов (template), на верхнем уровне.

Извлечение из словаря с помощью функции `key('list', .)` происходит очень быстро, что существенно улучшает производительность (это заметно при больших объёмах).